# Visual Studio 2012 crash on adding controller MVC4

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Anyone had this issue?

I opened an MVC4 project and all was working fine until I tried to add a controller, VS crashed so I restarted, now the project won't load at all and I get "waiting for an internal operation to complete" which never completes.

I removed resharper and tried the project on another system, I get exactly the same issue when   I add a new controller :(

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My fault, I had copied the project from SkyDrive and Windows 8 had locked all my DLLs - had fun unlocking them all!