# Visual Studio 2012 Freezes while adding a new ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-distributed-file-system

My MVC 4 project is located on Distributed File System (DFS). Everything works like a charm, but recently I found that creating a controller (right click on Controllers -> Add - > Controller...) freezes VS. After a while popup shows "VS is busy..." and it never completes an action.

So, the problem is: previously it worked OK and now it freezes.

The only way I can create a controller is to go "Add - New Item - > Controller", but I'm missing some nice details added by wizard.

If I move project into my local drives, it works without a problem.

The best link I've found by now is [this](http://digioz.blogspot.com/2013/06/visual-studio-2012-freezes-or-crashes.html). Similar issues are reported to Microsoft but there is no clear solution.
Also, [Visual Studio 2012 crash on adding controller MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317045/visual-studio-2012-crash-on-adding-controller-mvc4) is similar question but not applicable for this problem.

Sure, network location with project's files is set as trusted.

No useful info in event viewer. OS is Win7.

Anyone with similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to my admin, we have a solution. The problem occurs **only with mapped drives**.

Therefore, use absolute path instead of mapped drive!

For me, the problem has been solved. Sure, the question remains – why is that so?